# rspec: "describe MyClass::Something do"

Tags: ruby, testing, syntax, rspec

I'm new to `rspec`. The following syntax is confusing:

```
describe MyClass::Something do
```

What does `Something` refer to? The `rspec` tests I'm looking over contain the above line. However `MyClass` doesn't contain anything related to `Something`.

Comment: Are you sure MyClass::Something isn't defined somewhere else ? If this is not the case, you should have a Name Error when running your specs.

Comment: I do receive the name error. I think these particular tests may just be out-dated. In general what would `Something` refer to? Another class?

Comment: Names beginning by a capital letter are just constants. It could be a class, a module or an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confused by Ruby syntax, not RSpec syntax. `MyClass` is a module, and `Something` is a class or module inside the `MyClass` module. The `::` is the scope resolution operator to tell Ruby which `Something` you are looking for.

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def say_hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo::Bar.new
foo.say_hello
#prints "hello"
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html for more on modules.

Comment: To be even more precise, MyClass could also be a class which is a module. (Class inherits from Module)

Comment: Could `Something` even be an unusually named method?

Comment: You could have a method called `Something` in a module named `MyClass`, but then you would access it with `MyClass.Something`, not `MyClass::Something`. Not sure how this would affect RSpec though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Rspec. The answer you are seeking is that `Something` is an inner class or module within `MyClass`. `Something` refers to a class/module named `Something` within the class/module `MyClass`. Here is an example:

```
class MyClass
  module Something
  end
end
```